# How to get symbol address on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a library for accessing Objective-C from Python. I'm stuck on getting the address of variables on iOS.

Let's say i want to get the pointer address of `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey`:

```
NSString *key = CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey;
NSLog(@"Address is: %p\n", key);

NSString *key2 = dlsym(RTLD_SELF, "CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey");
NSLog(@"Address2 is: %p\n", key2);
```

I got:

```
Address is: 0x3a827fcc
Address2 is: 0x3a825514
```

Why do i get different values? I tried to look up with `RTLD_NEXT`, still get the same value. Is the objective-c variables are mangled somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dlsym()` gives you the *address* of the `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey`
variable, not its *contents*, which is a pointer to the Objective-C string.

```
NSLog(@"Address  is: %p\n", & CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey);
NSLog(@"Key      is: %p\n", CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey);

void *addr2 = dlsym(RTLD_SELF, "CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey");
NSLog(@"Address2 is: %p\n", addr2);
// Dereference pointer to get its contents:
NSString *key2 = *(NSString * __unsafe_unretained *)addr2;
NSLog(@"Key2     is: %p\n", key2);
```

Output:

```
Address  is: 0x7fff78950388
Key      is: 0x7fff7894ec08
Address2 is: 0x7fff78950388
Key2     is: 0x7fff7894ec08
```

Comment: How could i be so dumb. Thanks you.